# plotly 2 or more column based subplot

Tags: python, plotly

I am new to plotly and wanted to visualize some data. I got this plot. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJlKS.png)
But I want to get this in 2 or more column based so that it can be seen better.
Can someone help me with that. Here is my source code what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(data2, x = "Total_System_Cost", y= "Total_CO2_Emissions",
                        color="Pol_Inst", symbol="Pol_Inst",
                        facet_row='Technologie',width=600, height=3500)
fig.show()
```

And the data looks like this.[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbfeU.png)

Comment: Hi @shakhawat, and welcome to SO. Please have a look at [mcve](/help/mcve) and [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask). In particular share code or data as text not pictures so it will be easier for other users to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use `facet_col` and `facet_col_wrap` as in this [example](https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/#wrapping-column-facets)

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(data2, 
                 x="Total_System_Cost",
                 y="Total_CO2_Emissions",
                 color="Pol_Inst",
                 symbol="Pol_Inst",
                 facet_col='Technologie',
                 facet_col_wrap=2, #eventually change this
)

fig.show()
```

If you then want to use `width` and `height` do it so according to `data2['Technologie'].nunique()` and the value you picked for `facet_col_wrap`.